# Logstash config: conditional with list not working if [field] in ["list item 1"]

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I am using Logstash to process some flow data. Now I came across a problem while tagging the data using a conditional.

If I write the following in the logstash config

```
if [myfield] == "abc"{ mutate { add_tag => ["mytag"] } }
else { mutate { add_tag => ["not_working"] } }
```

everything works just fine, but now I want to use a list like

```
if [myfield] is in ["abc"]{ mutate { add_tag => ["mytag"] } }
else { mutate { add_tag => ["not_working"] } }
```

and only get a not_working tag.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems as if there has to be **more than one value in the array/list**. You could just duplicate the only value like

```
if [myfield] in ["abc", "abc"] { mutate { add_tag => ["mytag"] } }
else { mutate { add_tag => ["not_working"] } }
```

and it is working fine.

Comment: I found I had to exclude the `is` from this code for it to work: `if [myfield] in ["abc", "def"]`

Answer (score 4):

This is indeed a bug, here a link to Github: https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/9932